# NSTextView not resizing properly after setFrameSize

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

In an NSTextView subclass I have created, I want to resize the height of the view to the height of the text within it. To execute this, I used apple's recommended procedure of counting lines within a text view:

```
private func countln() -> Int {
    var nlines: Int
    var index: Int
    var range = NSRange()
    let nGlyphs = lManager.numberOfGlyphs
    for (nlines = 0, index = 0; index < nGlyphs; nlines++) {
        lManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &range)
        index = NSMaxRange(range);
    }
    return nlines
}
```

This method works as expected and returns the correct number of lines in the text view. The issue lies in the resizing of the view, which I inserted into the delegate method that is called on text change:

```
func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let newHeight = CGFloat(28 * countln())
    let ogHeight = self.frame.height
    self.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: self.frame.width, height: newHeight))
    self.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: (self.frame.origin.y - self.frame.height) + ogHeight))
    Swift.print(frame.height)
}
```

The `setFrameSize` variable function resizes the height of the view based not the number of lines in the view (multiplied by a constant that is more-or-less the height of each line of text). Everything works perfectly until immediately after the change of height is made, when the text view's height changes to an unanticipated incorrect height. I presume there is an issue with the frequent redrawing of the view in relation to the way I am resizing it. Any help on how to solve this issue of incorrect height resizing is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you possibly using constraint in your storyboard?

Comment: @YuchenZhong the view is being added programmatically with no constraints, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Why did you tag iOS?

Comment: @beyowulf mistake, I removed it